# readlines produces an empty list Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a game of hangman. When I try to read the file with a list of words it returns an empty array.

Code:

```
#Making a game of hangman
import random

def rand_word(file_name):
    # Retrieves a random word from a file
    f = open(file_name, "r")
    for num_lines, words in enumerate(f):
        pass
    num_lines += 1
    print(num_lines)
    rand_line = random.randint(1,num_lines)
    print (rand_line)
    file = f.readlines()
    print(file)
    f.close()

rand_word("words.txt")
```

Comment: What do you think this does?  `for num_lines, words in enumerate(f): pass`?

Comment: when you `enumerate` through `f`, you're moving the file pointer. By the time you actually call `readlines` the filepointer points at the end of the file, so there is nothing left to read. Your loop does nothing anyway, so just remove it.

Comment: I thought that the loop would count the number of lines in the file and then that way I can choose a random line to pick a random word and then when I call readlines it would read all the lines in the file then I could go on to pick a random line from there.

Answer (score 3):

You exhausted the file when looping over it in your `for` loop, so when you use `readlines`, you're at the end of the file and there's nothing left to read.

You should read your words in a list first, then choose a random one from the list:

```
import random

def rand_word(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        words = f.readlines()
    word = random.choice(words).strip()
    return word
```

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted, seems to be a good fix for the problem.